# How to extract all file in a .tar.gz to specific folder with cmake add_custom_target?

Tags: windows, cmake, tar

To decrease library size, used `cmake -E tar "zcvf" "lib.tar.gz" out.lib` in cmake to automatically create `.tar.gz` then `lib.tar.gz` is moved to folder `f`, ie.  `f/lib.tar.gz`.

However, to use this library in another project, it's needed to extract to specific folder. The command without cmake is clear: `tar -xzf f/lib.tar.gz -C target-folder`.

The problem is that, in cmake, how to combine `cmake -E tar "xzf" f/lib.tar.gz` with `-C` option?  Commands such as `cmake -E tar "xzf" f/lib.tar.gz -C f/` will result error.

Ideal script would be sth. like

```
add_custom_target(PrepareLib
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}  -E tar "xzf" command....
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} ## note, this line must not be modified
    )
```

Tools version: Visual Studio 2017, Windows 10 and CMake 3.17.1.

Comment: It seems that `cmake -E tar` doesn't support `-C` option. You may use pattern `cd <dir> && <command>` for switch current directory when executing `<command>` (this pattern works in `add_custom_target` unlike to `execute_process`). The better approach would to use `WORKING_DIRECTORY`. If different COMMANDs in `add_custom_target` require different working directories, then you may **split** this target into separate `add_custom_target`/`add_custom_command` and adjust appropriate dependencies between them.

Comment: ``COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E rename <extracted_directory> <destination_directory>`` as a second command after extraction